# Using Amazon SDK on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

We are using amazon sdk for sns push notifications. We deployed our app on Google App engine. While using amazon sdk we are getting following exception

```
 Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.<init>(AmazonSNSClient.java:128)
```

Looks like is it because of Sockets/Threads using by Amazon SDK.

Is there anyway to use amazon sdk on google app engine application.

Comment: Did you search for a solution before asking here? Did you evaluate this? https://github.com/apcj/aws-sdk-for-java-on-gae

Answer (score 0):

Which App Engine environment are you using?  (standard or flex).  App Engine standard may require the use of the Sockets API or UrlFetch for outbound connections, which won't always work with open source libraries (today).

One option here is to deploy your app to [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/hello-world), which won't have the same requirements.